# How to compute the pseudoinverse of a rank deficient transform of an SPD matrix in terms of the inverse of the SPD matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Say we have a symmetric positive definite matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ of which we know the inverse $A^{-1}$. We also have a rank deficient matrix $P\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, and we consider the singular array $A' := P^TAP$. Now, we are interested in the pseudoinverse $A'^+$. Ideally, I would not want to have to compute the pseudoinverse from scratch, but rather use the fact that we know $A^{-1}$. A naive attempt is to distribute the pseudoinverse assuming $(AB)^+ = B^+A^+$ irrespective of $A$ and $B$. By doing so, we get $P^+A^{-1}(P^T)^+$. However, I realized later that the pseudoinverse does not generally distribute, so that $P^+A^{-1}(P^T)^+$ is actually not equal to $A'^+$. So my question is the following, does there exist a way to compute $A'^+$ which makes use of $A^{-1}$?

Answer (score 0):

The beginning of an attempt: Since $A$ is PSD, we can [decompose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_matrix#Decomposition) it as $A = B^T B$, $B$ being invertible. Then $P^T A P = P^T B^T B P = (BP)^T BP$.

Now this satisfies one of the [sufficient conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Products) (let's take $C = (BP)^T$), so

$$
\big[(BP)^T BP\big]^+ = \big[C C^T\big]^+ = (C^+)^T C^+
$$

Will update further as I think about it. This might be the best we can do however.

Edit: By [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/457378/192336), we can maybe compute $(BP)^+$, tbd.